# Making Multidimensional char string in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, char

I'm trying to make a program that print all the data in a multidimensional array, only characters: can you tell me what's wrong with this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char vetor [1][6] = {{'S', 's', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'c' }};
    int i;
    int x;

    for(i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
        for(x=0;x<1;x++)
        {
            if (vetor[i][x]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your program never attempts to print the data. It only calls `printf()`.

Comment: What is that empty `if`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a `printf()` to the vector... Something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

        char vetor [1][6] = {{'S', 's', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'c' }};
        int i;
        int x;


    for(i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
        for(x=0;x<1;x++)
        {
            printf (" %c", vetor[i][x]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: wow! I was so busy trying tot make a the char array, that i completely forgot that i switched the printf for a if. Thank all you :)

Comment: If the answer help you, you should accept the answer, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work. Maybe you are new here, and you can learn how to do it in this link :)

Answer (score 0):

The first dimension of the array has length 1, the second length 6,
then, when using the array, `if (vetor[i][x]);` the dimensions are switched (`i` loops from 0 to 5, `x` from 0 to 0)